# Alternate Jenkins Build crashes

Tags: jenkins, crash

Every alternate Jenkins build crashes with the following error:

```
FATAL: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.run(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:123)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.calcChangeLog(SubversionSCM.java:725)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:860)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Jenkins version: 2.19.4

Comment: Was it solved? and if Yes, how?

Comment: We have this issue, did you ever find a solution?